# How I can compare the elements of two different dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, compare

I'm not fumiliar with python.
I have two data frames

```
  df= pd.DataFrame(
   [['p','r','c'],
    [ 'o','k','a']])
  df2=pd.DataFrame(
   [['p'],
    ['a']])
```

To see if elements of df2 are in df.columns, and if yes to return the indexes of the cell.
I tried this code:

```
        for col in df:
            for i in range(len(df2):
                for j in range(len(df2.columns)):
                    if df2[i,j] == df [col]:
                       Print(col)
                    else:
                       Print('not found')
```

But it is not working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the isin function to test values. Here, for clarity, I added a couple of lines to the original dataframe. In the loop, the values of the df2 dataframe are sorted out, a check is made for the presence of a value (if at least one element matches in the string, then the any function will return true). The so-called Boolean mask is used, which will return the desired indices: df.index. The lines that match the conditions, the list of indexes, and the value used for the search are printed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['p', 'r', 'c'], ['o', 'k', 'a'], ['q', 'q', 'q'],
                   ['q', 'a', 'q']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['p'], ['a']])


for i in range(len(df2)):
    ind = df.index[df.isin([df2.loc[i, 0]]).any(axis=1)]
    print(df.loc[ind])
    print('index', ind)
    print('df2.values', df2.values[i][0])
```

Output

```
   0  1  2
0  p  r  c
index Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
df2.values p
   0  1  2
1  o  k  a
3  q  a  q
index Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64')
df2.values a
```